# Licensing error message with BeCubed 6

Tags: c#, licensing, versioning

#### Boring introduction:

In my workplace, we have a very old WinForms product (in market since 1994, and still running on VB3). It has three very different versions, each of them goes to one client. The clients pass it on to their users, some of which are shared. The versions can live side-by-side.

Five years ago, we rewrote one of those versions in C#.Net. Two years later, another version (let's call it version M) was rewritten, and two years after that, it was time for the last remaining version (let's call it version C) to be converted. We've been working for one year, and are going to production this week.

During the conversions, it has been decided not to convert anything that was sold as an external module; these were built in VB6, and they used several controls from [BeCubed](http://www.becubed.com/index.htm) and [FarPoint](http://www.fpoint.com/). There are two such modules in version M, and three modules in version C.
Each module has it's own MSI installer, which is run quietly by the main product's installer.

#### The bug

During production, we found a bug: when version C in installed on a fresh computer, then version M is installed, we get a message as soon as an external module is opened in version C:

[image: BeCubed error]

After clicking Ok, the module works. Also, this doesn't happen when they are installed in any other order and both modules in version M work perfectly.

#### Other details

- All OCX and DLL files have been compared through all the module setups; the files are identical.
- All modules work when only one version M or C is installed, or when M is installed first.
- We have licenses for all the software we use, including BeCubed.

---

Does anyone know what could cause such an error, what could be a possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, one of the modules installed the OCX's to the system directory (default `C:\Windows\System`), and the others installed them to a program files directory (`C:\Program Files\CompanyName\Shared Files`). That probably causes a conflict in doubly registering the OCX's or something like that. I have no idea what was wrong there, but when we changed the one module to install in the `Shared Files` folder like everyone else, the problem was fixed. I'm writing this here so if anyone has a similar problem, he could check to make sure all the files are installed at the same location.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as nothing is changed to the file maybe something is changed in the registry.

But this seems like an issue you should contact BeCubed for, ask them how to turn on extended logging or ask them for support.

Right now there is not enough information to know what really happens...